# how to get link parameter in blade page in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

i want to get the parameter from laravel link in the blade page
below is the laravel ahref to navigate to the page

```
<a href="listElement/{{$user->element_id}}"
```

the link that i navigate to is the below

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/listElement/1
```

i want to get the parameter in the url to send it again to another ahref route like this

```
  <a href="{{ route('element.addElement','1') }}" //how to replace the 1 here
```

below are the controller function

```
public function addElement(Request $request)
{
return view('attribute.addAttribute',['id'=>$request]);

  }
```

this is the first link

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/listElement/1
```

and this is how i am navigate to add element page with the parameter

```
 <a href="{{ route('attribute.addElement',$request) }}"
```

Comment: <a href="{{ route('element.addElement',$user->element_id) }}"></a>

Comment: !!! what is $user here?? i am in another page now

Comment: sorry but this is not clear ..pass what to what

Comment: if still not working then please post  listElement route and related route controller  method

Comment: ok i am trying now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In controller method

```
public function addElement(Request $request,$id)
{
   return view('attribute.addAttribute',['id'=>$id]);

}
```

You can pass as second parameter to route  in new view

```
 <a href="{{ route('attribute.addElement',$id) }}"></a>
```

Comment: `<a href="{{ route('element.addElement',$id) }}"></a>` $id is not defined

Comment: can you update question with route and related method in controller as well as blade

Comment: so in the blade page addElement how to get this paraneter

Comment: you need route for example  Route::any("listElement/{id}",[\App\Http\Controllers\YourController::class,'addElement']);

Comment: it should be <input name="id" type="hidden" value="{{ $id }}" />

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234232/discussion-between-malo-and-john-lobo).